# How do I make a vertical menu like the one in the Google Play app?

Tags: android, android-menu

How would I make a vertical menu like the one pictured below? This style menu is also featured in other Google apps like YouTube and Chrome. I tried searching Google but didn't find anything relevant.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For sdk 17, you can use the SplitActionBar, it is an option available on the default ActionBar.

```
    <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
```

You can see this example

> http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-action-items-and-overflow-menu-items-to-action-bar-in-android/

And to support in all versions, use Action bar sherlock library.

> http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard Android [Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html), where menu items in the overflow (i.e., not shown on the Action Bar) are shown. Per the [Compatibility design page](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/compatibility.html), devices with a hardware menu key show these in a vertical menu.